# How to remove QBSDK13 to get the QBSDK12 OSR

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

How to you remove QBSDK13 so that we can get the QBSDk12 OSR with QBOE support?

We have removed QBSDK13 from the Control Panel (XP in this case).

But if we go into `C:\Program Files\Intuit\IDN\QBXML12\Doc\HTML` and click on `GettingStarted.html` then on the ON Screen Reference icon we get the QBSDK13 one.

We even renamed `C:\Program Files\Intuit\IDN\QBXML13` but it didn't help.

Is there no way to fall back?

Or how can we get a OSR for QBSDK12 so we can clearly see QBO? Sliding the Max SDK Version does not help.

Actually if you look at a non-supported requests in the OSR it shows the Max values even though the object (transaction) is not supported in the SDK for QBO.

Answer (score 0):

The OSR does not have QBOE support, period. It is only for QuickBooks desktop.

If you need QBOE documentation, you need to refer to Intuit's website:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

Comment: I understand that QBSDK13 does not support QBO.  But that was not the question. The question is how to remove QBSDK13 (on XP in this case) so that we can get the QBSDK12 OSR.  Since even after un-installing it we still get the QBSDK13 OSR and no QBO checkbox.